# Summation with system of aligned equations as lower limit

Tags: math-mode, align, environments

I'm trying to write a summation with a system of aligned equations as lower limit. To do that I wrote:

```
$$
I_{P+AH, a} = \sum
_{\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align*}
 &\tau_i \text{ ATTIVO} \\
 &d_i < d_{a_i} 
\end{empheq}}
c
$$
```

but Texmaker gives me an error (bad math environment). How can I do it?

Comment: Hi @Mico I need only to align the two equations of the system in a way that d_i will be aligned with tau_i

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's are `array`-based and `smallmatrix*`-based solutions. (Many thanks to @daleif for suggesting the second solution type.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
I_{P+AH, a} 
= \sum_{
  \Bigl\{ \begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
             \tau_i \textsc{ attivo} \\
             d_i < d_{a_i} 
          \end{array} }
c 
= \sum_{
  \bigl\{ \begin{smallmatrix*}[l]
             \tau_i \text{ \scshape attivo} \\
             d_i\, <\, d_{a_i}
          \end{smallmatrix*}}
c
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer.

Comment: IMO this just looks too large. Would `smallmatrix*` be better?

Comment: @daleif - Many thanks for this great suggestion. I've incorporated it in an update to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You're getting an error because you try to use `empheq` inside another math environment, which doesn't make sense. However, you don't really need `empheq` for that, you can just use `substack` surrounded with `\left\{ ... \right.`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
I_{P+AH, a} = \sum_{\left\{ \substack{
     \tau_i \text{ ATTIVO} \\
     d_i < d_{a_i}
} \right.}
c
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the conditions to be left-aligned, you can follow @daleif's suggestion and use a `subarray` environment instead of `\substack`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
I_{P+AH, a} = \sum_{\left\{ \begin{subarray}{l}
     \tau_i \text{ ATTIVO} \\
     d_i < d_{a_i}
\end{subarray} \right.}
c
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, it is not related to your problem, but [you should not use `$$...$$`, you should use `\[...\]` instead](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/201628).

Comment: Hello @Vincent, thank you for your help. How can I shift the second equation to the left side so that the d_i is aligned with tau_i?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi   `\substack` is basically the same as `\begin{subarray}{c} ... \end{subarray}` so use that instead with `{l}` instead of `{c}`

Comment: Hello @daleif can you post an example of the requirement I asked to Vincent please?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi that is exactly what I already wrote. And what Vincent changed the code to.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi I updated my answer with a second solution.

Comment: Thank you very much @Vincent

Comment: The (lack of) spacing around the `<` symbol in the second row below `\sum` doesn't look good.